# The code shows no error but the application is crashed

Tags: android

The app crashes automatically here but shows no error

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1, b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        b2.findViewById(R.id.btn2);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent1.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Open();

                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am here why to fear", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast2.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void Open() {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Main2.class);
        startActivity(intent2);


    }
}
```

*italic*
I can't find the error on this code but the application file is not opening. it says the application has stopped

Answer (score 1):

Change this Code

```
    b1.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    b2.findViewById(R.id.btn2)
```

With

```
 b1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
 b2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this Code

```
b1.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
b2.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
```

With

```
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
```